# How to disable help in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have mapped 'tilde' key (under escape on mac) to autocomplete, I just find it easier that way. At times I instead hit F1 accidentally and the IntellJ help pops up. Is there a way that I can disable F1 from activating help?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes. Press `Ctrl+Alt+S` and go to the `Keymap` tab in settings. Then find the "Context Help" node in `All Actions/Other/Context help`, and remove the shortcut.

You can look for other bound shortcuts in the future (by the key used to activate them) using the "filter" icon to the right of the search box.

[image]